# Expression for Potential energy of a hanging mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, potential-energy, conventions

If the acceleration due to gravity is $g$ and a mass $m$ is hanging from a fixed support with a thread of length $l$, then it's potential energy ($U$) is given by:

$$U = -mgl;$$

This was stated by my instructor.

However, the potential energy must be:

$$U = mgh;$$ where $h$ represents the vertical height above ground.

Why is PE stated in terms of distance from fixed support and in terms of height above ground? How does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential energy is never an absolute value - it is always measured relative to some base configuration or point that is assigned zero potential energy. And the location of this base point is arbitrary. So if we take the base point as being at ground level then the mass is a distance $h$ above the base point and its potential energy relative to the ground is $mgh$. However, if we take the base point as being at level of the support then the mass is a distance $l$ *below* this point and its potential energy relative to this base point is $-mgl$.

When solving problems we are only ever interested in the *difference* in potential energy between two different positions or configurations, so the choice of a base point for PE makes no difference to the final result. A good choice of base point may, however, make calculations simpler - for example, if you chose a base point on the opposite side of the Earth then you would be making the problem more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to choose a reference frame. It's not mandatory to choose the origin at the level of the ground, it's possible to choose the origin wherever you want but you must be consistent with the definition of work.
Choosing the origin in the ground level
$$W=\int_{y_A}^{y_B} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}=\int_{y_A}^{y_B} (mg(-\hat{y})\cdot dy \hat{y})=-\int_{y_A}^{y_B}mg=-mg(y_B-y_A)=-\Delta U$$
Thus, defining $U=mgy$ you get $$W_{A,B}=-mg(y_B-y_A)=U_A-U_B$$
Because $U_A=mg\cdot 0=0$, $y_A=0$ and $y_B=h$
The result would be $$\Delta U=U_B-U_A=+mgh$$ $$U_A=0$$ $$U_B=mgh$$
While choosing the origin in the maximum height reached by the body you have $$\Delta U=U_B-U_A=+mgh$$  $$U_A=-mgh$$ $$U_B=0$$
So, the variation is the same but the potential in the two point is changed in sign due to your choice of the reference frame. Of course using the energy conservation you need the $\Delta U$ not the absolute $U$